# Scrapy Python, Force spider to wait if encounter error page on multiple spider, multiple page scraping using CrawlerProcess?

Tags: python, asynchronous, web-scraping, scrapy

So I'm scraping a multi-page multi-categories pages on a website. The problem is that the website often returns corrupted/error data that are random, but checkable, sometimes due to my slow connection, other times because of unknown factors. Sometimes it even returns captcha. One way that I tried and works perfectly to solve the problem is to repeat the process but to wait 30 seconds or so.

Now the using Scrapy's own CrawlerProcess the script run asynchronously as intended looping through every page on both categories independent of one another. However if, lets say, category_1 hits an error page, both spiders pause, which leads to a significantly longer run time

my code looks something like this

```
class catergory_1(scrapy.Spider):
    pagenum = 0
    def parse(self, response):
        url = 'foobar.foo/category1/page=' + str(pagenum)
        #some scraping logic here
        #also checks whether the returned data is corrupted
        if isDataError == 1:
            print('page error, retry in 30 secs')
            time.sleep(30)
        elif isDataError ==0 and pagenum <= maxpage:
            print(data_1)  
            self.pagenum += 1
        else:
            CloseSpider()

class catergory_2(scrapy.Spider):
    pagenum = 0
    def parse(self, response):
        url = 'foobar.foo/category2/page=' + str(pagenum)
        #some scraping logic here
        #also checks whether the returned data is corrupted
        if isDataError == 1:
            print('page error, retry in 30 secs')
            time.sleep(30)
        elif isDataError ==0 and pagenum <= maxpage:
            print(data_2)  
            self.pagenum += 1
        else:
            CloseSpider()

process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
process.crawl(catergory_1)
process.crawl(catergory_2)
process.start() # the script will block here until all crawling jobs are finished
```

Is there any possible way so that if any of the spider hits the error page, the other spider could still run and would not have to wait as well?

Thank you!

Comment: Instead of sleeping on an error, you could adjust the concurrency and delay settings of the second spider through the `custom_settings` spider attribute. If a sleep call does the trick, you can probably find a regular concurrency and delay that will prevent these issues from happening at all.

Comment: I have never play with the custom settings, is it possible to change the delay dynamically based on the update? For example if Error delay = 30 if not Error delay =5?

Comment: It is possible, but you would have to write an extension. You could write one based on the code of the [AutoThrottle extension](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/autothrottle.html).